# Get Count Of Nested Entities using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have got 3 database tables clients, coupons and categories

```
clients table
```

id,
name,
website,
description,
logo,
slug

```
categories table
```

id,
name,
slug

```
coupons table
```

id,
client_id,
category_id,
type,
coupon,
title,
description,
link,
views,
slug,
expiry

The relationship is 
1) many coupons belongs to client ( many to one relationship)
2) many coupons belongs to category ( many to one relationship)

I am using laravel 5.1.

How can i get the unique count of clients with the clients details , number of coupons a client has and the count of total categories an individual client has.

simplified : i need to get the client details and display that xxx number of coupons are available in the xxx number of categories for a particular client.

so far i can get the unique client details and the number of the coupons count.

```
 public function getAvailableClientsWithItemCountList($page = 1)
{
    return Client::join('coupons', 'clients.id', '=', 'coupons.client_id')
        ->join('categories', 'coupons.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->where('coupons.expiry', '>', Carbon::today())
        ->groupBy('clients.id')
        ->skip(STORES_PER_REQUEST*($page-1))
        ->take(STORES_PER_REQUEST)
        ->get(['clients.id', 'clients.name', 'clients.slug', 'clients.logo', DB::raw('count(clients.id) as dealsCount'), DB::raw('count(categories.id) as categoriesCount')]);
}
```

STORES_PER_REQUEST = 9 (constant) for paginating.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i figured out myself with additional info as coupon type and the categories available.
The key i did was just added the case in count and removed the join of the categories table.

the final code looked like this

```
return App\Client::join('coupons', 'clients.id', '=', 'coupons.client_id')
    ->where('coupons.expiry', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::today())
    ->orderBy('clients.position', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('clients.id')
    ->skip(STORES_PER_REQUEST*(1-1))
    ->take(STORES_PER_REQUEST)
    ->get(['clients.id', 'clients.name', 'clients.slug', 'clients.logo', DB::raw('count(clients.id) as total'), DB::raw('count(CASE WHEN coupons.type=\'Coupon\' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as couponsCount'), DB::raw('count(CASE WHEN coupons.type=\'Deals\' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as dealsCount'), DB::raw('count(Distinct category_id) as categoriesCount')]);
```

The result was

```
[{
"id": "8",
"name": "Archies Online",
"slug": "archies-online",
"logo": "Archiesonline.jpg",
"total": "22",
"couponsCount": "20",
"dealsCount": "2",
"categoriesCount": "9"
}, {
"id": "5",
"name": "Shop Clues",
"slug": "shop-clues",
"logo": "Shopclues.jpg",
"total": "24",
"couponsCount": "24",
"dealsCount": "0",
"categoriesCount": "9"
}, {
"id": "6",
"name": "Lens Kart",
"slug": "lens-kart",
"logo": "Lenskart.jpg",
"total": "25",
"couponsCount": "25",
"dealsCount": "0",
"categoriesCount": "8"
}, {
"id": "7",
"name": "Amazer",
"slug": "amazer",
"logo": "Amzer.jpg",
"total": "21",
"couponsCount": "21",
"dealsCount": "0",
"categoriesCount": "8"
}, {
"id": "1",
"name": "Flipkart",
"slug": "flipkart",
"logo": "Flipkart.jpg",
"total": "17",
"couponsCount": "17",
"dealsCount": "0",
"categoriesCount": "9"
}, {
"id": "2",
"name": "Make My Trip",
"slug": "make-my-trip",
"logo": "Makemytrip.jpg",
"total": "11",
"couponsCount": "11",
"dealsCount": "0",
"categoriesCount": "8"
}]
```

This did the trick for now :);

Answer (score 0):

If you have your relationships set up you could do something like:

```
 /**
 * Mock relationship for eager loading coupon count
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function couponCount()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Coupon::class)
        ->selectRaw('client_id, count(*) as aggregate')
        ->groupBy('client_id');

}

public function getCouponCountAttribute()
{
    // if relation is not loaded already, let's do it first
    if (!$this->relationLoaded('couponCount')) {
        $this->load('couponCount');
    }

    $related = $this->getRelation('couponCount');

    // then return the count directly
    return ($related) ? (int) $related->aggregate : 0;
}
```

The above can be used in your `Client` model, and then you can just alter the `couponCount` relationship method for your `Category` model (if you wanted to).

Then add the following for your `Category` count:

```
 /**
 * Mock relationship for eager loading category count
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function categoryCount()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Coupon::class)
        ->selectRaw('category_id, count(*) as aggregate')
        ->groupBy('client_id, category_id');

}

public function getCategoryCountAttribute()
{
    // if relation is not loaded already, let's do it first
    if (!$this->relationLoaded('categoryCount')) {
        $this->load('categoryCount');
    }

    $related = $this->getRelation('categoryCount');

    // then return the count directly
    return ($related) ? (int) $related->aggregate : 0;
}
```

You can then add a query scope in your `Coupon` model for getting coupons that haven't expired by something like:

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    $query->where('expiry', '>', Carbon::today());
}
```

If you're only ever going to be getting the count for coupons that haven't expired you can add you can add this straight on to the relationship e.g.
`groupBy('client)id')->active()`

Now you should be able to eager load the relationship like so:

```
 $clients = Client::with('couponCount', 'clientCount')
    ->skip(STORES_PER_REQUEST * ($page - 1))
    ->take(STORES_PER_REQUEST)
    ->get();
```

Or you could attach the query scope to the eager load i.e.

```
 $clients = Client::with(['couponCount' => function ($q) {$q->active()}, 'clientCount' => function ($q) {$q->active()}]) ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you.. I figured out myself after wasting the whole day searching the solution.